# What camera do you offer to a beginner for his first dslr or dslr like

Tags: camera-recommendation

I'm new on photography, actually not new yet. I'm confused on which camera to choose for my first. There is up to 400$ in my packet for my first camera. I've searched alot and found two main dslr like cameras; Canon Sx50 hs and Sony HX300.

But then, I read some posts about high noise on higher iso levels on dslr like cameras such these two. Then I tried to find an entry level dslr camera but couldn't find, because I don't know about cameras. Could you please help me on this?

Comment: We have a number of questions along these lines. See http://photo.stackexchange.com/search?q=Bridge+dslr+is%3Aquestion+

Comment: BTW, ALL cameras suffer from higher noise at higher ISO levels - if it's bad enough to mention in a review though, I would avoid it. Here's an example of high ISO from the Sony Alpha - it's grainy but not bad... http://www.flickr.com/photos/77816686@N02/9491169620/

Comment: Really impossible to recommend a camera for someone you don't know.  What sorts of photography would you do?  Family snapshots, flowers in the garden, sports, travel, indoors, outdoors?  Is size/weight important? 

And are you looking for general recommendations on cameras or just wanting a specific answer on the ISO issue?

Answer (score 1):

You are going to be extremely limited at $400 for budget.  Even the cheapest entry level DSLRs are normally $500 or more and for $400 you're barely moving above basic components for anything.

If you plan to get in to photography, I'd suggest waiting until you can afford an entry level DSLR, and then you can work on improving lenses over time as your skills improve and eventually get a better camera body if you find it is something you enjoy.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Actually there is a camera that I want to get; canon eos 100d. Butit's much more expensive. If you say that it worths to wait for it, I think I'll wait for a month to get it.

Comment: @HalilIbrahim - yeah, the big advantage to getting a DSLR isn't just that it is easier to get used to the basic concepts of photography, but also that you can reuse parts of your investment.  If you go Canon for example, any lenses you get for the 100D can be used if you later decide to get something like a 60D and if you get EF lenses, they could even be used with the highest end Canon DSLRs.  You can get better optics to improve the body you have and then get a better body to improve what you get from the lenses you have already.

Comment: I dunno, I got my D40 + kit lens refurbished for $375. Cameta right now has the D5100 going for $360 (but no lens). If you shop around and buy refurb/used you could get started with that. Photography doesn't HAVE to be expensive.

Comment: @KaushikGhose - that's true, you can try used, but I generally shy away from it since you don't know how the gear has been cared for and poor care WILL negatively impact the gear.  This can be a particular problem for lower end gear too.  If you decide to go used, be sure to use someplace reputable.

Comment: @AJHenderson, yes used off ebay or somewhere is dicey. However, refurb comes with a warranty (shorter, but a warranty never-the-less).

Answer (score 1):

If you can stretch your budget a little bit, you might be able to afford a relatively modern DSLR like [this Canon T3i refurb](http://www.adorama.com/ICAT3IKR.html). A manufacturer-refurbished camera will come with a warrantee and will have been checked out and repackaged by the manufacturer, so it's nearly new, but they can't sell it as "new".

The next best option is to buy a used camera from a reputable source. Adorama and B&H are two dealers that have solid reputations. The key here is to know what you're getting -- is it just the body, or does it come with a lens? How about a battery, charger, and other accessories? Caveat emptor. That goes triple if you buy through Ebay -- something I wouldn't recommend for a beginner.

Answer (score -1):

The Sony Alpha 65 has recently dropped in price and I think it's a very nice entry-level DSLR (really, SLT but you don't care about that right now). The camera has all the features and functions, and the same sensor, as Sony's high end pro camera, and it has very nice auto modes. When you're new, you want a camera with good automatic features, because you're going to be concentrating mostly on composing good shots, and you want to be able to do that quickly without worrying about whether your focus or white balance will be correct. The Sony A65 really shines in that area with its quick and accurate auto-focus and scene detection adjustments. It can be a completely manual camera as well, and I've needed that in some situations but not very often.

Here are some photos taken by a beginner with the Alpha 65: http://www.flickr.com/photos/77816686@N02/sets/72157635006651404/  (in that set, there's lots of action shots, some landscape shots, one panorama, and even some time exposures, one with lightning in it)

http://store.sony.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10551&storeId=10151&productId=8198552921666586450&langId=-1&k_id=5a5f1592-cd97-d6c9-ab33-00001ba4ac0d&kpid=8198552921666586450&XID=O:slta65vl:dg_gglsrch:pla&cagpspn=pla&gclid=CJvy3tT16bkCFS1p7AodzFsAPg

BTW, yes, I'm agreeing with the previous poster that you should try to increase your budget if you can.

Comment: Note that you're still talking 2x the stated budget.

Comment: In the link yeah, but the A65 is selling for $650 at some places right now.